# woocommerce add-to-cart url unicode issue

Tags: php, wordpress, unicode, woocommerce

I'm having an issue with product attribute names that use unicode, when I try to generate URLs to add products to the cart. For example:

`http://example.com/?add-to-cart=2215&variation_id=2216&attribute_option=0`
works fine, but when I try:

`http://example.com/?add-to-cart=2215&variation_id=2216&attribute_option-한=0`

or the wordpress slug version:

`http://example.com/?add-to-cart=2215&variation_id=2216&attribute_option-%ed%95%9c=0`

the cart fails to update, with an error message that I need to enter a value for that attribute field.

Ideas? I need to use unicode in the attribute names since otherwise customers won't be able to read them.

Answer (score 0):

Why You just change the attribute SLUG in wordpress to English Characters?
I think that is the best solution.